# How can I save Graphics2D canvas to image file

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel, graphics2d

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java Swing : Obtain `Image` of JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853879/java-swing-obtain-image-of-jframe)

In my java program I would like to save a Graphics2D canvas which is a JPanel as an image. I am asking for classes necessary for this and suggestions thank you. I hope I have been clear enough. I have not added a code example because I don't think it is necessary.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349220/convert-jpanel-to-image), with exactly the same problem.

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12984207/cannot-convert-current-canvas-data-into-image-in-java/12984332#12984332 just for fun