# How to load/save an Image from a JPanel

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel, javax.imageio

I'm missing the export file code, but I have no clue as to what I need to add. I have a drawn image in a JPanel -> panel and want to save that image into my desktop. What do I need to add?

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.showOpenDialog(panel);
```

I've added the following code to my paintComponent method:

```
bi = new BufferedImage(panel.getSize().width,panel.getSize().height,
          BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
g = bi.createGraphics();
```

And then the Save Button does this... What else am I missing? Or doing incorrectly more so.

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.showSaveDialog(panel);

try{ImageIO.write(bi,"png",new File("test.png"));}catch (Exception ex) {}
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12984207/cannot-convert-current-canvas-data-into-image-in-java/12984332#12984332) and let me know if it's the same problem

Comment: @MadProgrammer  Now *that* was an inspired answer that deserves more than the "me & some other 'guy'" votes it got.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're question is missing some important information: how are you drawing things on the JPanel? In my opinion, the smart way would be to draw into a BufferedImage, and then simply save the BufferedImage to file using `ImageIO.write(...)`

**Edit**
You state:

> I'm just drawing polygons onto a class that extends JPanel. I create them via the paintComponent method.

Again, I recommend that you draw them to a BufferedImage, by getting its Graphics context, drawing to the image using this Graphics object, and then disposing the Graphics object. You would display the BufferedImage in your JPanel's `paintComponent(...)` method by calling `g.drawImage(...)`. Then if you want to save the drawing, again, simply save the BufferedImage.

Comment: I'm just drawing polygons onto a class that extends JPanel. I create them via the paintComponent method. I have a save button that will run the code above.

Comment: @James: please the re-iteration of my recommendation in the edit to my answer.

Comment: *"the smart way would be to draw into a BufferedImage, and then simply save the BufferedImage"*  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12683533/drawing-a-rectangle-that-wont-disappear-in-next-paint/12683632#12683632) for an example.  Alternately to gain a snapshot of the panel (less preferable) see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853879/java-swing-obtain-image-of-jframe/5853992#5853992).

Comment: I've updated what I have so far, hopefully I am on the right track, but still am missing something.

Comment: *"still am missing something. "*  **Start with** changing.. `catch (Exception ex) {}` to `catch (Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }`