# How to let user draw inside a canvas and save image afterwards?

Tags: java, swing, canvas, jframe, drawing

I am trying to implement a free hand drawing Java applet which allows user to draw something in canvas (canvas is not the priority, it could be anything else as long I can save the image after (need to save it, because I have to display it later in a different place after pressing a button, any other solutions are welcome)). I found a code, which allows me to draw, but now I am having a trouble with drawing inside the canvas... And I have already spent few days with no results on that. Here is the code I have by now and a description below it:

```
    import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class paintMozApplet extends Applet implements ActionListener
{
    int xPressed,yPressed;
    int xReleased,yReleased;
    int xDragged,yDragged;
    private GridLayout gL;
    private JPanel buttons;
    private JPanel panel;
    private Button clear, createMoz;
    private Label  result_here;
    private javax.swing.JPanel drawing;
    private JPanel moz;
    private Canvas canvas;
    private draw draw;

    public paintMozApplet()
    {
        draw = new draw();

        gL = new GridLayout(1, 0);          

        buttons = new JPanel();
        drawing = new JPanel();
        moz = new JPanel();
        canvas = new Canvas();

        clear = new Button("clear");
        createMoz = new Button("Create Moz");

        buttons.add(clear);
        buttons.add(createMoz);

        result_here = new Label("Result here!");

        moz.add(result_here);
        drawing.add(canvas);

        clear.addActionListener(this);
        //canvas.add(draw);
        //canvas.addMouseMotionListener(this);

        canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        canvas.setBackground(Color.green);

        add(drawing);
        add(buttons);
        add(moz);
        add(draw);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 1000));

        setSize(1000, 1000);
        setLayout(gL);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
         if(e.getSource()==clear)
        {
            //setOpaque(false);
            repaint();
        }
    }

}
class draw extends JFrame implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener, ActionListener {

    int xPressed,yPressed;
    int xReleased,yReleased;
    int xDragged,yDragged;
    private JButton clear;
    public draw()
    {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1200, 500));
        setBounds(0, 0, 480, 500);
        clear=new JButton("CLEAR");
        add(clear);
        clear.setBounds(540, 5, 100, 25);
        clear.addActionListener(this);
        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }        

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawLine(xPressed,yPressed,xDragged,yDragged);
        xPressed=xDragged;
        yPressed=yDragged;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {
        Graphics g = getGraphics();
        g.drawLine(xPressed, yPressed, arg0.getX(), arg0.getY());
        xDragged = arg0.getX();
        yDragged = arg0.getY();
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
    }
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
        xPressed = arg0.getX();
        yPressed = arg0.getY();
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    }

}
```

So my idea is to create two classes where one is used to draw and other to create place where to draw and everything else. I have tried lots of things and now I am here and cant figure out, how to cal the draw class on my canvas so it will draw only there. Before I had everything in one class and called mouse events on my canvas. Result was that it drawed only when I clicked on canvas, but the actual drawing went also out of canvas if I did not let go of my mouse and dragged it out of canvas. Also it did not draw in canvas, but on the background of applet, at least it looked like that.

I really hope I explained my self understanding and I am sure, that this can be solved easily since there are lots of solutions online but I can't seem to find one that would work as I intend.

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12984207/cannot-convert-current-canvas-data-into-image-in-java/12984332#12984332)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest starting with this approach based around a `BufferedImage` as the painting surface..

[image: Basic paint app.]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.RenderingHints.Key;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

public class BasicPaint {

    /** Reference to the original image. */
    private BufferedImage originalImage;
    /** Image used to make changes. */
    private BufferedImage canvasImage;
    /** The main GUI that might be added to a frame or applet. */
    private JPanel gui;
    /** The color to use when calling clear, text or other 
     * drawing functionality. */
    private Color color = Color.WHITE;
    /** General user messages. */
    private JLabel output = new JLabel("You DooDoodle!");

    private BufferedImage colorSample = new BufferedImage(
            16,16,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    private JLabel imageLabel;
    private int activeTool;
    public static final int SELECTION_TOOL = 0;
    public static final int DRAW_TOOL = 1;
    public static final int TEXT_TOOL = 2;

    private Point selectionStart; 
    private Rectangle selection;
    private boolean dirty = false;
    private Stroke stroke = new BasicStroke(
            3,BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND,BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND,1.7f);
    private RenderingHints renderingHints;

    public JComponent getGui() {
        if (gui==null) {
            Map<Key, Object> hintsMap = new HashMap<RenderingHints.Key,Object>();
            hintsMap.put(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
            hintsMap.put(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
            hintsMap.put(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            renderingHints = new RenderingHints(hintsMap); 

            setImage(new BufferedImage(320,240,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB));
            gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(4,4));
            gui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5,3,5,3));

            JPanel imageView = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            imageView.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(480,320));
            imageLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(canvasImage));
            JScrollPane imageScroll = new JScrollPane(imageView);
            imageView.add(imageLabel);
            imageLabel.addMouseMotionListener(new ImageMouseMotionListener());
            imageLabel.addMouseListener(new ImageMouseListener());
            gui.add(imageScroll,BorderLayout.CENTER);

            JToolBar tb = new JToolBar();
            tb.setFloatable(false);
            JButton colorButton = new JButton("Color");
            colorButton.setMnemonic('o');
            colorButton.setToolTipText("Choose a Color");
            ActionListener colorListener = new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    Color c = JColorChooser.showDialog(
                            gui, "Choose a color", color);
                    if (c!=null) {
                        setColor(c);
                    }
                }
            };
            colorButton.addActionListener(colorListener);
            colorButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon(colorSample));
            tb.add(colorButton);

            setColor(color);

            final SpinnerNumberModel strokeModel = 
                    new SpinnerNumberModel(3,1,16,1);
            JSpinner strokeSize = new JSpinner(strokeModel);
            ChangeListener strokeListener = new ChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent arg0) {
                    Object o = strokeModel.getValue();
                    Integer i = (Integer)o; 
                    stroke = new BasicStroke(
                            i.intValue(),
                            BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND,
                            BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND,
                            1.7f);
                }
            };
            strokeSize.addChangeListener(strokeListener);
            strokeSize.setMaximumSize(strokeSize.getPreferredSize());
            JLabel strokeLabel = new JLabel("Stroke");
            strokeLabel.setLabelFor(strokeSize);
            strokeLabel.setDisplayedMnemonic('t');
            tb.add(strokeLabel);
            tb.add(strokeSize);

            tb.addSeparator();

            ActionListener clearListener = new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    int result = JOptionPane.OK_OPTION;
                    if (dirty) {
                        result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
                                gui, "Erase the current painting?");
                    }
                    if (result==JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
                        clear(canvasImage);
                    }
                }
            };
            JButton clearButton = new JButton("Clear");
            tb.add(clearButton);
            clearButton.addActionListener(clearListener);

            gui.add(tb, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

            JToolBar tools = new JToolBar(JToolBar.VERTICAL);
            tools.setFloatable(false);
            JButton crop = new JButton("Crop");
            final JRadioButton select = new JRadioButton("Select", true);
            final JRadioButton draw = new JRadioButton("Draw");
            final JRadioButton text = new JRadioButton("Text");

            tools.add(crop);            
            tools.add(select);          
            tools.add(draw);            
            tools.add(text);

            ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
            bg.add(select);
            bg.add(text);
            bg.add(draw);
            ActionListener toolGroupListener = new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                    if (ae.getSource()==select) {
                        activeTool = SELECTION_TOOL;
                    } else if (ae.getSource()==draw) {
                        activeTool = DRAW_TOOL;
                    } else if (ae.getSource()==text) {
                        activeTool = TEXT_TOOL;
                    }
                }
            };
            select.addActionListener(toolGroupListener);
            draw.addActionListener(toolGroupListener);
            text.addActionListener(toolGroupListener);

            gui.add(tools, BorderLayout.LINE_END);

            gui.add(output,BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
            clear(colorSample);
            clear(canvasImage);
        }

        return gui;
    }

    /** Clears the entire image area by painting it with the current color. */
    public void clear(BufferedImage bi) {
        Graphics2D g = bi.createGraphics();
        g.setRenderingHints(renderingHints);
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight());

        g.dispose();
        imageLabel.repaint();
    }

    public void setImage(BufferedImage image) {
        this.originalImage = image;
        int w = image.getWidth();
        int h = image.getHeight();
        canvasImage = new BufferedImage(w,h,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        Graphics2D g = this.canvasImage.createGraphics();
        g.setRenderingHints(renderingHints);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, gui);
        g.dispose();

        selection = new Rectangle(0,0,w,h); 
        if (this.imageLabel!=null) {
            imageLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(canvasImage));
            this.imageLabel.repaint();
        }
        if (gui!=null) {
            gui.invalidate();
        }
    }

    /** Set the current painting color and refresh any elements needed. */
    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
        clear(colorSample);
    }

    private JMenu getFileMenu(boolean webstart){
        JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
        file.setMnemonic('f');

        JMenuItem newImageItem = new JMenuItem("New");
        newImageItem.setMnemonic('n');
        ActionListener newImage = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(
                        360, 300, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                clear(bi);
                setImage(bi);
            }
        };
        newImageItem.addActionListener(newImage);
        file.add(newImageItem);

        if (webstart) {
            //TODO Add open/save functionality using JNLP API
        } else {
            //TODO Add save functionality using J2SE API
            file.addSeparator();
            ActionListener openListener = new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    if (!dirty) {
                        JFileChooser ch = getFileChooser();
                        int result = ch.showOpenDialog(gui);
                        if (result==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION ) {
                            try {
                                BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(
                                        ch.getSelectedFile());
                                setImage(bi);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                showError(e);
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        // TODO
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                                gui, "TODO - prompt save image..");
                    }
                }
            };
            JMenuItem openItem = new JMenuItem("Open");
            openItem.setMnemonic('o');
            openItem.addActionListener(openListener);
            file.add(openItem);

            ActionListener saveListener = new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JFileChooser ch = getFileChooser();
                    int result = ch.showSaveDialog(gui);
                    if (result==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION ) {
                        try {
                            File f = ch.getSelectedFile();
                            ImageIO.write(BasicPaint.this.canvasImage, "png", f);
                            BasicPaint.this.originalImage = BasicPaint.this.canvasImage;
                            dirty = false;
                        } catch (IOException ioe) {
                            showError(ioe);
                            ioe.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            JMenuItem saveItem = new JMenuItem("Save");
            saveItem.addActionListener(saveListener);
            saveItem.setMnemonic('s');
            file.add(saveItem);
        }

        if (canExit()) {
            ActionListener exit = new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            };
            JMenuItem exitItem = new JMenuItem("Exit");
            exitItem.setMnemonic('x');
            file.addSeparator();
            exitItem.addActionListener(exit);
            file.add(exitItem);
        }

        return file;
    }

    private void showError(Throwable t) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                gui, 
                t.getMessage(), 
                t.toString(), 
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

    JFileChooser chooser = null;

    public JFileChooser getFileChooser() {
        if (chooser==null) {
            chooser = new JFileChooser();
            FileFilter ff = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Image files", ImageIO.getReaderFileSuffixes());
            chooser.setFileFilter(ff);
        }
        return chooser;

    }

    public boolean canExit() {
        boolean canExit = false;
        SecurityManager sm = System.getSecurityManager();
        if (sm==null) {
            canExit = true;
        } else {
            try {
                sm.checkExit(0);
                canExit = true; 
            } catch(Exception stayFalse) {
            }
        }

        return canExit;
    }

    public JMenuBar getMenuBar(boolean webstart){
        JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
        mb.add(this.getFileMenu(webstart));
        return mb;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                            UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // use default
                }
                BasicPaint bp = new BasicPaint();

                JFrame f = new JFrame("DooDoodle!");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                f.setContentPane(bp.getGui());
                f.setJMenuBar(bp.getMenuBar(false));

                f.pack();
                f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }

    public void text(Point point) {
        String text = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(gui, "Text to add", "Text");
        if (text!=null) {
            Graphics2D g = this.canvasImage.createGraphics();
            g.setRenderingHints(renderingHints);
            g.setColor(this.color);
            g.setStroke(stroke);
            int n = 0;
            g.drawString(text,point.x,point.y);
            g.dispose();
            this.imageLabel.repaint();
        }
    }

    public void draw(Point point) {
        Graphics2D g = this.canvasImage.createGraphics();
        g.setRenderingHints(renderingHints);
        g.setColor(this.color);
        g.setStroke(stroke);
        int n = 0;
        g.drawLine(point.x, point.y, point.x+n, point.y+n);
        g.dispose();
        this.imageLabel.repaint();
    }

    class ImageMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (activeTool==BasicPaint.SELECTION_TOOL) {
                selectionStart = arg0.getPoint();
            } else if (activeTool==BasicPaint.DRAW_TOOL) {
                // TODO
                draw(arg0.getPoint());
            } else if (activeTool==BasicPaint.TEXT_TOOL) {
                // TODO
                text(arg0.getPoint());
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                        gui, 
                        "Application error.  :(", 
                        "Error!", 
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
            if (activeTool==BasicPaint.SELECTION_TOOL) {
                selection = new Rectangle(
                        selectionStart.x,
                        selectionStart.y,
                        arg0.getPoint().x,
                        arg0.getPoint().y);
            }
        }
    }

    class ImageMouseMotionListener implements MouseMotionListener {

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {
            reportPositionAndColor(arg0);
            if (activeTool==BasicPaint.SELECTION_TOOL) {
                selection = new Rectangle(
                        selectionStart.x,
                        selectionStart.y,
                        arg0.getPoint().x-selectionStart.x,
                        arg0.getPoint().y-selectionStart.y);
            } else if (activeTool==BasicPaint.DRAW_TOOL) {
                draw(arg0.getPoint());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {
            reportPositionAndColor(arg0);
        }

    }

    private void reportPositionAndColor(MouseEvent me) {
        String text = "";
        if (activeTool==BasicPaint.SELECTION_TOOL) {
            text += "Selection (X,Y:WxH): " + 
                    (int)selection.getX() +
                    "," +
                    (int)selection.getY() +
                    ":" +
                    (int)selection.getWidth() +
                    "x" +
                    (int)selection.getHeight();
        } else {
            text += "X,Y: " + (me.getPoint().x+1) + "," + (me.getPoint().y+1);
        }
        output.setText(text);
    }
}
```

This source is very patchy.

- It has many parts with `// TODO`
- A `dirty` attribute is declared but never used in any meaningful way.  ..

It is just something I hacked together today and thought should be shown before it hit the posting limit.

Oh, and don't go looking for any 'OO design' since I did not put any in.  If there is any, it is only by accident.  This code is intended to demonstrate what is possible and how to start doing it.